# Typo3 fluid view as a modal dialog

Tags: fluid, extbase

For my typo3 extbase extension, I have a view which just a form for uploading pictures.On form submission, the user is redirected to another view. Now, I want to display this fluid view with the form as a modal dialog.Is this possible and if yes, how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Use your domain model.

1) Assign a new domain model to your view:

```
public function formAction(Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_MyObject $newMyObject = NULL) {
    $this->view->assign('newMyObject', $newMyObject);
}
```

Your form should look like:

```
<f:form action="post" name="myObject" object="{newMyObject}">
  <f:form.textbox property="name" />
  <f:form.textbox property="surname" />
  etc..
</f:form>
```

2) Send the form values as object to your post/show/dialog action, add the object via the repository and assign it to your view:

```
public function postAction(Tx_MyExt_Domain_Model_MyObject $myObject) {
    // saves the object
    $this->myObjectRepository->add($myObject);
    $this->view->assign('object', $myObject);
}
```

Another way without using a domain model looks like:

```
public function postAction() {
   $arguments = $this->request->getArguments();
   $this->view->assign('arguments', $arguments);
}
```